# Add invisible grid or rectangle over a PictureBox

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio

I'm trying to create a monopoly game using windows form application. I add a PictureBox which contains a picture of monopoly board. What I was thinking was to add invisible grids or rectangular components from the toolbox over each token on the boards. Then I use these tokens to track where the player go, once they roll the dices. This is a screenshot of my current progress:

[image: current progress screenshot]

There are two questions I'd like to ask.

1. What is the component in toolbox I can use as a grid?
2. How can I put grids over a PictureBox so these grid covers all the tokens on Monopoly board?

Thanks

Comment: FYI you can "roll", "cast" or even "throw" dice, but "draw" is not correct in this context. (Button text in screenshot)

Comment: `Then I use these tokens to track where the player go` Based on this quote and your question in general, does that mean you're giving the player the freedom to move the pieces, and your game will **track** the location of the pieces? Because that's going to be considerably harder than having the game move the pieces for the player. If your game keeps control of the board, your game will automatically know where everything is.

Comment: @Manfred Radlwimmer Thanks for reply, I changed it to Roll Dice

Comment: @Flater Thanks for your reply. My plan is to allow two players to play the game, both of them start at "GO" space. But in order to track their position, I'd like to put something over the PicktureBox, so I can know their location and call other method such as BuyProperty(), GivingTax(), GoJail().  The PictureBox has a picture of Monopoly board.

Comment: @C.Mi: That's what I'm referring to. You're giving the player the freedom to move his piece **wherever he wants**, and then your application will **figure out** where he place the piece. But it would be much easier if **the application moves the piece for the player**. That way, your game knows where the piece is (because the application put it there), and you don't need to try and figure out what the player has been doing (which is going to cost a lot of effort to implement, for no discernible benefit).

Comment: @Flater for the part " the application moves the piece for the player", I'm a bit confused. Given that I have put position of each space such as Park, Jail, Houses into a List or Dictionary, does it mean that if a player has rolled dices, the program will handle the number of dices and give the player his position?

Comment: @C.Mi: Yes. Assuming a player is on Start, and then rolls the dice (result = 7), then the application already knows where to put the player's piece (i.e; on the Chance square). You don't need the player to move the piece for you. Having the player do it for you means that you need to develop logic to confirm whether the player moved it correctly. If you move it for him, you don't need additional logic to confirm that it's correct.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a [TableLayoutPanel](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.tablelayoutpanel(v=vs.110).aspx), where you set the BackroundImage to your Monopoly-Board.

You can then use `tableLayoutPanel1.Controls` to iterate through your controls.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I've tried your suggestion, but the right side of Monopoly-Board covered by another column of TableLayoutPanel, which contains textbox and several buttons. Can I resize the background picture?

Comment: Sure, check out the `BackroundImageLayout` and change it's value to zoom